# Apache Cordova Visual Studio 2015 iframe

Tags: javascript, cordova, iframe

IFrame does not work at all. IFrame loads only the HTML, HEAD and BODY tags like here:

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body></body>
</html>

//iframe is called in index.html
<iframe src="http://whatever.com" style="height:100%; width:100%;"></iframe>
```

InAppBrowser and other stuff is working.

How to do it correctly?

Why does IFrame not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally did it! So solution for my IFrame.

**HTML HEAD:**

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no;" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

**IFrame:**

```
<iframe src="http://somewebsite.com" sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-popups allow-forms" id="activityFrame" style="width:100%; height:100%;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

**config.xml:**

```
<access origin="*" />
<access origin="http://somewebsite.com" /> //OR you can add it to Visual studio Dialog
<preference name="websecurity" value="disable" />
```

And everything should work well.

I hope it help someone else. :)

Comment: well, it seems that your problem was about cross-origin not the iframe, the question is misleading

Comment: Well, but this should be helpful for someone who have same issue as me.

Answer (score 1):

I use this and works fine for both ios and android "with scrolling enabled"

```
<div style="width:100%;height:100%;overflow:scroll !important;-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch !important">
  <iframe src="http://whatever.com" scrolling="yes" style="width:100%;height:100%" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: This has the same result like before.

Comment: Did you try the target page of your iframe in a browser individually, it may contains js error prevent it from being rendered well

Comment: Yes, but every time is same result. I have tried a lot of pages but every time is same result.